# IBM MobileFirst 7.1 push subscription user id empty

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I have a MobileFirst app that only sees some occasional use by the customer (an iOS Enterprise app). I updated it and when testing push notifications found out that push notifications were not being sent by the server.

```
var userSubscription = WL.Server.getUserNotificationSubscription("XXXAdapter.invoiceMessages", userId);
```

returned undefined. Upon inspecting the database I found out that almost all push subscriptions (`PUSH_SUBSCRIPTIONS` table) for the adapter listed `USER_ID` as empty. I removed them and subscribed from the app again, but an empty user id was inserted again. The MySQL full log listed the transaction as follows:

```
284 Query     INSERT INTO PUSH_SUBSCRIPTIONS (CREATED_MODE, CREATED_TIME, LAST_UPDATED_TIME, ALIAS, OPTIONS,
STATE, TAG_NAME, USER_ID, DEVICE_ID) VALUES
('API', '2016-09-23T14:06:52Z', '2016-09-23T14:06:52Z', 'invoiceMessages', 
'{"alert":true,"badge":true,"sound":true,"requestHeaders":{}}', '{}',
'XXXAdapter.invoiceMessages', '', 14)
```

The adapter does list a valid user id when I log in:

```
Sep 23, 2016 4:06:40 PM com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptIntegrationLibraryImplementation info
INFO: Fri Sep 23 2016 16:06:40 GMT+0200 (CEST)Login result: {"resultSet":[{"id":8,"name":"Andrey"}],"isSuccessful":true} [project XXX]
```

As I said, the app only sees occasional use and I think it was upgraded from 6.2 or so almost a year ago, so it may be it hasn't been working since then. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please provide the exact version of MFP you are using  (complete with the build-id). There was a similar that has been fixed.

Comment: The MFP version is 7.1.0.00-20150807-0630

Comment: If you are able to recreate the issue on a test / UAT environment, will it be possible for you to install the latest iFix from FixCentral and try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current assumption is that this issue has been fixed in a recent iFix release. Login to IBM Fix Central and download the latest available iFix for MobileFirst Platform Foundation (currently 7.1.0.0-MFPF-IF201610060540) to verify that the issue has been resolved.

Comment: Thanks, Idan. The project was on hold for a certain time (due to unrelated reasons), and only now have I finished it. The latest MFPF version of the 7.1 branch (20170120) doesn't exhibit this behaviour anymore. Not sure what the reason was then (and if I hadn't overlooked anything that might have lead to it), but the remedy has worked anyway.